# How to access computed state variable?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-class-components, vue-property-decorator

Using Vue Class Component, how does one get the value of a computed variable? Trying to use `this.bar` gives an error: `Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'Vue'.`

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({
    computed: {
        bar() {
            return true;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        qux() {
            // How to get the value of bar here?
            if (this.bar) {
                baz();
            }
        },
    },
})
export default class Foo extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are not using the right syntax.

You should change what you have to this

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component  
export default class Foo extends Vue {
  get bar(): boolean {
    return true;
  }
  qux() {
    if (this.bar) {
        baz();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

For more on using Vue Class Components, check out this [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-write-a-vue-js-app-completely-in-typescript/)

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you do not wanna use getter?

```
@Component({})
export default class Foo extends Vue {
  get bar() { return true }
}
```

This is converted to computed property

Answer (score 0):

If you use vue-property-decorator everything goes to extended class.

Normal Vue:

```
export default {
  data(){
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    bar() {
        return true;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    qux() {
        if (this.bar) {
            baz();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The same in Typescript

```
@Component({})

export default class Foo extends Vue {
  get bar() {
    return true;
  }

  private qux() {
    if (this.bar) {
      this.baz();
    }
  }

  private baz() {
    //do smth
  }
}
```